# Thymeleaf doesn't show values

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing a little web-application using Spring-Boot & Thymeleaf, but the values pass from controller to html page doesn't appear.

I don't known why, but it doesn't work.

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--    thymeleaf   -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {".html", ".xhtml"});
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

This is the 
**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dyn")
public class DynamicWebPage {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/third", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView fileDinamicoTerzo() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("messagge", "ciao");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addAllObjects(model);
        mav.setViewName("forward:provadin.html");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

this is the html file, here i should see the value of data i passed through...
**html template**

```
<div th:text="${message}">${message}</div>
<div th:utext="${message}">${message}</div>
<div th:value="${message}">${message}</div>
<div data-th-text="${message}"></div>
<div th:inline="text">[[${message}]]</div>
<div th:inline="text">[[${model.message}]]</div>
```

and this is the **result**

```
${message}
${message}
${message}

[[${model.messagge}]]
[["${model.messagge}"]]
```

Is there some one could say me how fix this problem?

*I'm sorry for my english*

Comment: You are not runnig Thymeleaf

Comment: How can i do, for running thymeleaf?

Comment: For one thing, you are misspelling the word `message`, bro.  It reads `messagge`

Answer (score 0):

You are not running Thymeleaf at all. You need to "tell" Spring to use Thymeleaf as its template engine.

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html. Point 2 and 3

Comment: I followed steps 2 and 3, i wrote a ThymeleafConfig class with resolvers, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @VitoLipari Feel to free to update your question with mentioned config class

Comment: [This is my configuration class](https://github.com/vitolipari/spring-thymeleaf-learning/blob/master/src/main/java/com/liparistudios/learning/webjsonreact/conf/ThymeleafConfig.java)

Comment: Put this in qustion

Answer (score 0):

You are misspelling the word "message".

Let's also clean up your controller:

```
@Controller
public class DynamicWebPage {

   @GetMapping("/third")
   public String fileDinamicoTerzo(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("message", "ciao");
       return "provadin";
   }
}
```

Your HTML can have something like:

```
<span th:remove="tag" th:text="${message}">message</div>
```

Also, for future questions on SO, please remove anything that's not necessary in your question.  You don't need to post commented code.

Comment: I think something is missing, because it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace in @Configuration -> ThymeleafConfig.java

this : `templateResolver.setPrefix("/");`

with this : `templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/")`

I think your prefix is not valid. It needs to know whole path where your templates are.

Comment: Your answer is unclear, you have not explained at least what to do with the above instruction, remember stack-overflow is not just for solving the immediate problem but to provide a suitable explanation so that future readers understand the root cause of the problem and justifiable solution.